# Call a method from another method

Tags: c#, methods

I have this code:

```
        public void StartTimer()
        {
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += Something;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);
            timer.Start();

        }

        private async void Something()
        {      
         //code goes here....
        }
```

The problem is that I get this error:

> No overload for 'Something' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'

My question is probably basic: why I get this error and how can I fix it...

Comment: timr.Tick needs a method whose signature matches EventHandler, i.e. "void Something(object sender, EventArgs e)"

Comment: Even when I change it to: private async void Somerhing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) I get the same error

Comment: @Tal it's `EventArgs`, not `RoutedEventArgs`.

Comment: @Tal That's because it doesn't expect an `async` method, and it needs to accept `EventArgs`, not `RoutedEventArgs`.

Comment: It doesn't matter I get the same error...

Comment: @JLRishe `async` is not actually part of a method's signature, it's just a flag for the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

The property [`Tick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) is of type [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The signature of `EventHandler` is:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(
    Object sender,
    EventArgs e
)
```

Which means your `Something` method must match this signature. Change it to:

```
public void Something(Object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

Alternatively, if you can't change the signature of that method, you can create a new delegate that calls your method.

```
timer.Tick += (s, e) => Something();
```

Comment: Thanks, But when I change it to: private async void Somerhing(object sender, EventArgs e) I see the same error

Comment: The alternative in the bottom did work! But do you have any idea why the first suggestion doesn't work?

Comment: @Tal Don't know, it should have worked. The only reason I can think of is you made a typo (your comment mentions a method named `Somerhing`, not `Something`).

Comment: Ok, can you explain what the alternative code means pleas?

Comment: @Tal The alternative code simply wraps your method `Something` in a new anonymous method that calls `Something`. It's as if you had defined a new method like this: `void AnonymousMethod(object s, EventArgs e) { Something(); }` and then `timer.Tick += AnonymousMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`DispatcherTimer.Tick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event expects a handler that takes an `object` and an `EventArgs` argument:

```
private void Something(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of Something does not match that specific event. Look into the documentation for that event to see how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
        public void StartTimer()
        {
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += Something;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 3);
            timer.Start();

        }

        private async void Something(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
         //code goes here....
        }
```